# split csv file with awk and save to new files by column reformat

Tags: csv, awk

I'm trying to learn AWK
I have a large csv file, that we export from one system and needs to import into another system.

the CSV file is a product list:

```
"Varenr.";"Beskrivelse";"Lagerbeholdning";"M�rke Navn";"Forventet levering";"Varegrp. Nr.";"Varegrp. Navn";"Beskrivelse 2";"Beskrivelse 3";"EAN/UPC";"Bruttov�gt";"Nettov�gt"
"0-761345-00101-4";"Power Apt 90W, 19V /";"0";"Antec";"10-04-2020";"600090";"Tilbeh�r, b�rbare";"0-4.74A";"";"885909627561";"2,00";"0,50"
"0-761345-01142-6";"Gamer GX909 Window Midi Tower";"0";"Antec";"10-04-2020";"998000";"Feeds";"military";"";"5706998724038";"7,82";"7,04"
"0-761345-05552-9";"NeoECO 550C (550W) 80+ Bronze";"0";"Antec";"10-04-2020";"205022";"500-799W";"";"";"5706998878328";"2,00";"1,80"
"0-761345-05652-6";"NeoECO 650C (650W) 80+ Bronze";"0";"Antec";"10-04-2020";"998000";"Feeds";"";"";"";"2,26";"2,03"
"0-761345-06248-0";"1000W ATX 13,5cm High Curent P";"0";"Antec";"10-04-2020";"205023";"800-1000W";"";"";"5711783480815";"2,00";"0,50"
"0-761345-06260-2";"HCP 1300 PLATINUM-EC";"0";"Antec";"10-04-2020";"205023";"800-1000W";"";"";"7613450626022";"2,00";"1,60"
"0-761345-06484-2";"power supply unit 400w";"0";"Antec";"10-04-2020";"460565";"Power Supplies";"ATX Black";"15";"761345064842";"1,73";"1,56"
"0-761345-92025-4";"VSK-3000B-U3/U2 Mini Tower";"0";"Antec";"10-04-2020";"210120";"Minitower";"USB3 Blk";"";"761345920254";"3,73";"3,36"
"0-761345-92033-9";"VSK-3000E-U3 Mini Tower US B3";"0";"Antec";"11-05-2020";"210120";"Minitower";"Black";"";"761345920339";"6,00";"6,00"
"0-761345-92043-8";"VSK-4000E-U3 Mini Tower US";"0";"Antec";"11-05-2020";"210120";"Minitower";"B3 Black retail";"";"761345920438";"5,00";"4,00"
"0-761345-93100-7";"NSK-3100-EC Micro Tower Black";"0";"Antec";"10-04-2020";"210140";"Micro ATX";"";"";"761345931007";"4,00";"3,00"
"0-761345-93534-0";"ASK-3000B-U3 Mini Tower 2xUSB";"0";"Antec";"11-05-2020";"998000";"Feeds";"3.0 Blk";"30";"";"3,65";"3,29"
```

The file contains thousands of lines and I need to split the file into separate files based on the Category in column 7

I have so far been able to structure this and it works:

```
awk -F ';' 'NR==1{h=$0; next};!seen[$7]++{f=$7".csv"; print h > f};{f=$7".csv"; print >> f; close(f)}' input.csv
```

But this gives me a problem with the file names. So before the f variable is set I need to format the text to remove " and replace spaces, / and , with _

I have tried to figure out how to do this with sed, but I can't figure out how to insert that into awk or if awk has a similar function.

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?
And please, I don't just want a solution. I want to understand it :-)

Regards,
Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need pipelines to/from sed when you're using awk and you'd definitely never call sed from awk. `to format the text to remove " and replace spaces, / and , with _` from a variable that contains the value of $7 is:

```
var=$7
gsub(/"/,"",var)
gsub(/[[:space:]/,]/,"_",var)
```

Try this untested tweak to your existing code:

```
awk -F ';' '
    NR==1 {h=$0; next}
    { f=$7".csv"; gsub(/"/,"",f); gsub(/[[:space:]/,]/,"_",f) }
    !seen[f]++ { print h > f }
    { print >> f; close(f) }
' input.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the help So if I get it right. If forinstance I wanted to also replace backslas I would just add \\ after the comma in the gosub before the ]

Comment: Correct and you would need to escape backslash as you suggest, you actually don't need to escape the `/` as I had done inside a bracket expression so I'm updating that now from `\/` to just `/`.